# POST dynamic content from one Web API service to another

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am working with ASP.NET Web API 2. From my application, I need to post some dynamic content to anther Web API service. The destination service expects data in this format.

```
public class DataModel
{
    public dynamic Payload { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUTC { get; set; }
}
```

I am thinking of using something like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{                
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new  MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   dynamic payLoad = new ExpandoObject();    
   DataModel model = new DataModel();
   model.Payload = payLoad;    
   var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);    
}
```

What is the best way to post dynamic information from one Web API service to another in asynchronous way?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there...

Something like the following should work for you, according to want I can read in your question.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var url = new Uri("http://localhost:9000");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    dynamic payLoad = new ExpandoObject();

    DataModel model = new DataModel { Payload = payLoad };

    //Model will be serialized automatically.
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);

    //It may be a good thing to make sure that your request was handled properly
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    //If you need to work with the response, read its content! 
    //Here I implemented the controller so that it sends back what it received
    //ReadAsAsync permits to deserialize the response content
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DataModel>();

    // Do stuff with responseContent...
}
```